# Object attributes are not returned when using objectOutputStream

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app in Android Studio and as part of this, I want to save a Player object, mainly so I can keep a track of their longtime average score.

The Player object contains multiple variables `name` `average` `score` amongst others.

Some of the variables change with each turn and some will stay the same. At the end of each turn, most of them are reset to 0 but `average` will stay the same. the average is of type int as it needs a decimal value.

I have the following code which compiles and runs, but nothing happens, using debugger shows that it only seems to read the `FileOutputStream` but not the `ObjectOutputStream`

```
//Write data to file
        try{
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("myObject.txt"));
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
            o.writeObject(p1);
            o.close();
            f.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
//Read data from file
        try {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File("myObject.txt"));
            ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);

            p2 = (Player) oi.readObject();

            oi.close();
            fi.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

I have set up my object so it has attributes assigned to it. I have also tried a dumbed down version which just contains a `Player` object with only a `name` and `average`, but I still don't get any luck.

Please can anyone advise what I am doing wrong.

`Player` class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Player implements Serializable {

     String name;
    private int score;
    private float average;

    public Player(String aName){
        this.name = aName;
        this.average = 20f;
        this.score = 45;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+this.name + "\nScore: "+this.score+"\nAverage: "+this.average;
    }
}
```

This is the dumbed down version rather than showing the one with all the attributes.

Comment: Can you show your player class?

Comment: I have added it to the main question.

Comment: I tested your code locally and everything works. There must be something wrong in the code that you are not showing to us.